# Spring-Data for MongoDB exception while using @DBRef annotation for referencing

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

Here I am trying with @DBRef annotation for referencing object from another one in Spring-Data for MongoDB. But after running MongoApp class, result table data is getting inserted in DB but its showing no method found exception for Person object insert, like in following example. Whats happening here?

```
public class Result {

  @Id
  @NotNull
  private String subjectId;

  @NotNull
  private String subName;

  @NotNull
  @Max(value = 100)
  private int marks;

  public Result(String subjectId, String subName, int marks) {
    this.subjectId = subjectId;
    this.subName = subName;
    this.marks = marks;
  }
}

public class Person {


      @Id
      @NotNull
      private String abc;

      @NotNull
      @Size(max = 8, min = 4, message = "Not a Valid Name")
      private String name;

      @Max(value = 100)
      private int age;

      @DBRef(collection = "result")
      private Result result;

      public Person(String id, String name, int age, Result result) {
        this.abc = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.result = result;
      }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  String location = "com/springMongo/core/applicationContext-springdata.xml";
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(location);
  MongoOperations mongoOps = (MongoOperations) context.getBean("mongoTemplate");
  mongoOps.insert(new Result("1","Math",50));

  Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("subjectId").is("1"));
  mongoOps.insert(new Person("1212", "Ravi", 34, mongoOps.findOne(query, Result.class)));
}
```

After Running above application its Showing following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoPersistentProperty.isCollection()Z
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:448)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$5.doWithAssociation(MappingMongoConverter.java:433)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:420)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:351)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:316)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:592)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:554)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:545)
at com.springMongo.core.MongoApp.main(MongoApp.java:43)
```

Comment: Which version of spring data and mongodb driver are you using?

Comment: mongo-java-driver 2.7.2 ; spring-data-mongodb 1.0.0.M5 ;
spring-core 3.1.0.RELEASE ; spring-context  3.1.0.RELEASE ;
spring-data-commons-core 1.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a jar dependency issue wrt versioning.

Make sure you have the correct version of the mongodb driver jar which matches the correct version of the spring data jars.

Comment: I am using latest mongo-java-driver 2.7.2 and latest spring-data-mongodb 1.0.0.M5 but still its giving problem

Comment: Do you have any duplicate jars with multiple versions?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit odd as the `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown for a class within the very same JAR the original call results. Would you mind trying the following?

- Make sure you don't have multiple versions of `spring-data-mongodb-${version}.jar` in your classpath, output folder etc.
- Try using the latest 1.0.0.RELEASE version of Spring Data MongoDB
- Make sure you have Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Data Commons in matching versions as stated in the `pom.xml` of Spring Data MongoDB and in the reference documentation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, upgrading my dependencies solved the problem.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<!--   <version>1.0.0.M5</version> -->
   <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```